# SonarQube 7.1 and TFS 2018 Publish Quality Gate Results Fail

Tags: tfs, sonarqube

1. Created a build definition in TFS 2018
2. Add step Prepare analysis on SonarQube.
   3 Tokenizer: Transform Source Files
3. NuGet Restore
4. Build Solution: .NET
5. VsTest - testAssemblies
6. Run Code Analysis
7. Publish Quality Gate Result

   Step 8 Fails with below error:

   Evaluating condition for step: 'Publish Quality Gate Result'

   Evaluating: succeeded()

   Evaluating succeeded:

   (Boolean) True

   Expanded: True

   Result: True

   Starting: Publish Quality Gate Result

==============================================================================
2018-06-04T17:34:41.6970611Z Task         : Publish Quality Gate Result
2018-06-04T17:34:41.6971068Z Description  : Publish SonarQube's Quality Gate result on the VSTS/TFS build result, to be used after the actual analysis.
2018-06-04T17:34:41.6971496Z Version      : 4.2.0
2018-06-04T17:34:41.6971818Z Author       : sonarsource
2018-06-04T17:34:41.6972216Z Help         : [More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
2018-06-04T17:34:41.6972761Z ==============================================================================

```
agent.TempDirectory=D:\source\agent\_work\_temp

loading inputs and endpoints

loading 

ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN

loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION

loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION

loading INPUT_POLLINGTIMEOUTSEC

loading SECRET_SONARQUBE_ENDPOINT

loaded 5

Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined

Agent.CAInfo=undefined

Agent.ClientCert=undefined

Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined

SONARQUBE_SCANNER_PARAMS={"sonar.host.url":"http://localhost:9000/","sonar.login":"admin","sonar.password":"admin","sonar.projectKey":"nao-webapi","sonar.projectName":"nao-webapi","sonar.projectVersion":"1.0","sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths":"**/*.coveragexml","sonar.verbose":"true"}

SONARQUBE_ENDPOINT=********

API GET: '/api/metrics/search' with query "{"f":"name","ps":500}"
```

Response: 401 Body: "undefined"

```
API GET '/api/metrics/search' failed, status code was: 401

Could not fetch metrics

Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;][SQ] Could not fetch metrics

API GET '/api/metrics/search' failed, status code was: 401

Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;][SQ] API GET '/api/metrics/search' failed, status code was: 401

 Agent.BuildDirectory=D:\source\agent\_work\21

 defaultRoot: 'D:\source\agent\_work\21'

 findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'

 findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'

 matchOptions.debug: 'false'
```

I get the results, can't figure out why this is not working.

Comment: Its SonarQube 7.1 not 4.2 sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly (start changing the tile).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Did you queue builds in TFS? Could you share your build definition? 401 usually means `Unauthorized`, did you have permission to access your server?

Comment: Tried Linkhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544346/sonarqube-v-4-tfs-task-publish-analysis-result-throw-error-could-not-fetch-me?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa            But did not fix issue.

Comment: Is the latest SonarQube Extension compatible with TFS 2018 update 2

Comment: This is TFS 2018 Update 2, has update 2 been tested with extension?

Answer (score 0):

[The extension site](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) indicates, SonarQube extension works with:

- Visual Studio Team Services
- Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 2
- Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 3
- Team Foundation Server 2018

No TFS 2018 Update 2 yet.